# Is there a way to get browser information, including version number, from a background script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-detection

I want current platform information about the browser from a background script.

Firefox has a `runtime.getBrowserInfo` function that specifies a key `version`.

Short of having to import a package or to regex the user agent string, are there similarly elegant ways that leverage the chrome extension API?

Comment: No, there's none. You'll have to parse navigator.userAgent. It's trivial and doesn't need a package.

Comment: Maybe window.navigator.userAgent?

Comment: @woxxom parsing UA is far from trivial.  1) browsers often impersonate other browsers in their UA (eg chrome on mac reports "AppleWebKit/537 chrome/114 safari/537).  2) user can change UA to anything.  3) UA can even vary from site to site (extensions to set UA on per-site basis).  parsing UA is a disaster.  it only works in unaltered cases, otherwise strange errors that are hard to diagnosis.

Comment: UA inside the extension's background page/script doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Use `navigator.vendor` not `navigator.userAgent`.  Not great but it's the best option.  UA is unreliable and changes frequently.  In vendor look for:

- "Google" in chrome browsers
- "Apple" in safari browsers
- "" (empty) in firefox
- not sure about IE / Edge, confirm values for others

vendor is deprecated but it's a better solution while it still exists.  Once you know the browser, you can try picking out the appropriate version number from navigator.userAgent (version info doesn't exist anywhere else).  Just beware that the version could be wildly wrong if UA has been altered (by user, by vendor, by anyone else).

Be sure you really need browser detection and not capability detection.

### Long Answer

Parsing UserAgent strings (i.e. navigator.userAgent) is a terrible approach.  User agents (UA) are built on lies.  Look at this default chrome UA:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 31_32_33) AppleWebKit/456.78 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/196.0.0.0 Safari/456.78`

Right off the bat, chrome is impersonating Mozilla, WebKit, KHTML, and Safari.  Why Mozilla?  This goes back to the beginning of the web (early 90s), when [Netscape Navigator](https://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Netscape) ruled the roost.  Netscape's internal name was Mozilla.  Every browser since has been impersonating Netscape Navigator, a browser that's been dead for 20+ years.  And it continues: chrome also impersonates Apple Safari and KHTML.  Others will doubtless be added in the future.

### It gets worse

But it's much worse than that.  Besides impersonating other browsers, the UserAgent string is completely changeable.  The user can set UA string to anything they want. This is often done for security (hide platform details from webservers), privacy (prevent snooping), or to avoid poorly managed server restrictions (showing different content to different UAs).  UA can even vary in the same browser from site to site, with [extensions that set UA](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) on per-site basis.

Parsing UA is a disaster. It only somewhat works in base unmodified cases - until things change and everything breaks.  Browser makers update their UA strings all the time, with no guarantee of consistency.  Identifying a browser incorrectly can cause strange errors that are very hard to diagnosis.

You might say "So what?  I'm writing an extension. Doesn't matter if another extension changes the UA for certain sites.  My background script sees the real UA".  And you'd be wrong.

1. Users can and do set user-agent strings in their profiles.  These take effect browser-wide before any extensions are loaded
2. Your extension content scripts may not see the real UA.  This mismatch between background and content scripts creates headaches for your extension.  Managable with diligence, but a pain to handle.

### The best approach

Currently, the best way to diagnose browser is with [`navigator.vendor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vendor).  Why?

1. vendor is not part of headers sent in HTTP requests.  This means...
2. vendor is much less likely for websites to inspect (can only be done client side with scripts), which means...
3. there's much less incentive for user to change vendor string, and limited ways for them to do so

Firefox doesn't set vendor.  Chrome sets it to "Google Inc." and Safari sets it to "Apple Computer, Inc.".  Values may change slightly but checking for substring match of "Apple" or "Google" or empty is safe.

Not sure what Edge / IE do with vendor.  Maybe someone can post it in comments.

You can see all the strings in navigator with this in console:

`for (p in navigator) { value = navigator [p];  if (typeof value == 'string') { console.log ('' + p + ' = ' + value); } }`